# PostGIS mapbox vector tiles and custom projection

Tags: openlayers, postgis, vector-tiles

I'm trying to use PostGIS (ST_AsMVTGeom, ST_AsMVT) to generate mapbox vectortiles for OpenLayers (512x512 tile grid). But I'm getting oversimplified geometries for many zoom levels.

Looks like I can't use these PostGIS functions for custom projections (custom tile grid), different from web-mercator. Sometimes I
use raw 3D-model data without any wellknown coord system. What can I do? I use C# for backend.

Comment: Oversimplified geometries are due to functions buffer, isnt it?

Comment: No. After all it looks like OpenLayers (vectortilesource tile grid) setup issue. Trying to resolve